# useSWR returning undefined data with axios in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, swr

I have a useSubjects custom hook to fetch the data from my API endpoint that utilizes useSWR.

```
import axios from '@/lib/axios'
import useSWR from 'swr'

/**
 * Fetcher Function for SWR
 */
const fetchSubjects = async url => {
    console.log("url = " + url)
    await axios
        .get(url)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error
        })
}

export const useSubjects = (id = -1) => {
    // /**
    //  * swr hook for fetching subjects
    //  */
    const { data: subjects, error, mutate } = useSWR(
        id > 0 ? `api/get-subject-branch/${id}` : 'api/get-subject-branches',
        fetchSubjects,
    )

    return {
        subjects,
        error,
    }
}
```

The useSubjects hook is later used in one of my components.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSubjects } from '@/hooks/subjects'

const myComponent = () => {
   const { subjects, error } = useSubjects()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(subjects)
    }, [subjects])

   return (
      <>
         <div>My Content</div>
      </>
   )
}
```

However, the `constant {subjects}`  which should hold the fetched data from the useSWR hook seems to remain `undefined`

I have tested out my API endpoint using direct `axios` `GET` request and it successfully pulls the data from my API.

In fact, I have written `console.log(res.data)` in my `fetchSubjects` fetcher function that seems to get the data. But it is somehow it is not setting the `const {data: subjects, ...}` that should hold the data fetched from the API and it remains `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the fetcher ,
it should be

```
const fetchSubjects = async (url: string) => {
    console.log("url = " + url)
     return await axios
        .get(url)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error
        })
}
```

check this working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/swr-axios-forked-r4loo6